# Flixel files compiling in mxmlc but not running

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc, flixel

SETUP:
I'm brand new to Actionscript 3 and mxmlc, I'm running 64 bit Arch Linux with multilibs. Neither the Flex SDK nor flixel are provided nor supported by the Arch Linux distribution so I extracted them to ~/devtools/flexsdk and ~/devtools/flixel respectively. I've added the Flex SDK .../bin/ to my path and I've copied flixel's .../org/ into all my flixel project root directories.

PROBLEM:
Every HelloWorld.as that I have compiled that is pure as3 compiles and runs fine, but if I try to use the flixel library the resulting SWF displays a blank screen, either black or white. I can right click on the running SWF in the browser and it says "Movie not Loaded..." and "About Adobe Flash Player 11.2.202.258...". Happens in firefox 17 and chromium 23.

RESEARCH:
I've tried every flixel HelloWorld I could find including [Adam Atomic's](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/HelloWorld). All are plagued by this and the only error I get is the one telling me there isn't a preloader.

I compiled [EZplatformer](https://github.com/AdamAtomic/EZPlatformer) which has a preloader to see if this was the problem, it compiled with no errors whatsoever even using -debug=true but still the same blank screen.

QUESTION:
I'm guessing I need to do something more to set up flixel or to set up mxmlc to use flixel but I don't know what. Does anyone know what this problem is or where I went wrong? Is there anything in the flixel-master code that wouldn't be compatible with the Flex SDK 4.6 mxmlc?

Comment: Are you also running the SWF on a Linux computer? Flash on Linux isn't the best...I would try it on a Mac or PC and with any browser **except Chrome**. Chrome (on all OS's) uses the buggy Pepper Flash player (which ironically was meant to keep Flash working on Linux platforms).

Comment: I got the exact same problem (Can compile but getting black screen in either firefox or chromium). I asked a friend to test on her Mac the .swf I just compiled, but when se tried to execute it, flash automatically played the last game she played on flash, but not the one I compiled. I'm compiling on Lubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I'm almost positive this is happening at compile time and that it is happening between the flixel library and the compiler. My flash player works flawlessly on every flash and flixel game I've tried on the Internet including both of Adam's [online](http://flixel.org/helloworld/) [demos](http://flixel.org/EZPlatformer/), and I have not had this issue compiling HelloWorld or graphic drawing examples with pure Actionscript 3 that doesn't import flixel. I know flash is known to have kinks on Linux but nothing points to the player being the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, this works for me:

mxmlc -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true src/HelloWorld.as

Like this tutorial says, I hope you find this useful:

https://github.com/jcromartie/HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Linux isn't a nice platform for Flash. Lots of problems, and lack of support.

In my experience with as3 in Linux, a black screen indicates that the flash player didn't even start. So it's not a runtime error, but more likely a compilation incompatibility.
If I remember correctly, flash player in Linux was running for 32 bit systems only. For 64 bit support, you had to do some extra research.